# Dialog is not visible after activity coming back to foreground

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've a situation in 2.3, and the scenario is.

Listview in an activity, where alert dialog is displayed on list item long press and on simple tap, redirects to another Activity (B)

- long press on item, alert is displayed properly
- Close alert
- normal tap redirects to activity B
- close Activity B (gets back to Activity A)
- now long press on list item, now only black translucent blanket is displayed

[image] [image]

Right side screenshot is only displayed without clear dialog!!

**It only happens in 2.3, works just fine in 4.0 >**

How can I fix this? any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using fragment dialogs?

Comment: please post the relevant part of the code.

Comment: no I'm not using fragmentdialog, I tried that one too but same issue

Comment: @Simulant Its normal alertdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by changing TabsActivity to fragmentActivity, because google map was rerendered each time, so placed it in fragment and its fixed